# how to deploy angular application in nginx

Tags: angular

I want to deploy my angular application in the Nginx server, how I can do that.

I have tried a sample app, in my windows system,

when I run the below command, It created a dist folder:

```
         ng build --prod
```

In that dist folder when I click on the index.html page, the page is showing blank, I want to see the data whenever we open that index.html file in the browser.

How to solve these issues.

My folder structure:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvN6X.png)

Comment: Can you please share your ```angular.conf``` file too.

Comment: @ArpitJain   I am not seeing any angular.conf file in my folder structure, for your reference I have attached my folder structure.

Comment: Please follow this article this will helps you https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/deply-of-a-angular-application-on-iis/